# css a way to align absolute child div to right

Tags: css

Is there a way, by default, to right-align a child div that is `position: absolute` just using CSS. I know I can make it align to right using JavaScript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `right: 0px` as shown in this jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DayE3/

Comment: cool, but I guess the same isn't true if I wanted it to start bottom-left? I tried bottom: 0px

Comment: Yes, it applies to bottom to: http://jsfiddle.net/DayE3/1/ But if you want to have it at the bottom of the window (not at the bottom of the document / holder-div) you should use `position: fixed`

Answer (score 2):

I think it should work for you -

```
parent-div-css { overflow: hidden; }
child-div-css { clear:right; float:right; }
```